# DirectInput analogue joystick range

Tags: windows, directx, enumeration, directinput

I use DirectInput to handle input devices, I enumerate devices and elements on each device.

When using the analogue sticks on my game pad, they report values in the range 0-65535. Is this *always* the case for all types of absolute axis?

If not: is there any way to find out the range of an DX8 input element's DIDEVICEOBJECTDATA::dwData (enumerated with DIDFT_ABSAXIS)? The only other option I can think of is to use some home made internal calibration inside my app, and that sound too '80s to be true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Goz so sweetly put it, I did the following, which worked:

```
dev->EnumObjects(EnumElementsCallback, 0, DIDFT_ALL);

BOOL CALLBACK EnumElementsCallback(LPCDIDEVICEOBJECTINSTANCE dev, LPVOID)
{
    if ((dev->dwType & DIDFT_ABSAXIS) != 0)
    {
        DIPROPRANGE range;
        range.diph.dwSize = sizeof(DIPROPRANGE);
        range.diph.dwHeaderSize = sizeof(DIPROPHEADER);
        range.diph.dwHow = DIPH_BYID;
        range.diph.dwObj = dev->dwType;
        if (lDevice->mDIDevice->GetProperty(DIPROP_RANGE, &range.diph) == DI_OK)
        {
            ... = range.lMin;
            ... = range.lMax;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Can't you get the range using GetProperty and passing in an appropriate DIPROPRANGE structure to be filled?  Use the DIPROP_RANGE GUID.

Comment: This sounds like the answer for me, just have to implement and check. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From : [http://www.wingmanteam.com/files/Tools/DXTweak/Readme.txt](https://web.archive.org/web/20100216053909/http://www.wingmanteam.com/files/Tools/DXTweak/Readme.txt)

A game controller driver usually reports axis position information
as integer values between 0 and 655 to DirectInput. DirectInput
linearly scales these values up to 0 to 65535.